# python dict() sorting by default

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I'm parsing hl7 to json. I opened the file and created an array where each line is an array like so...

```
[['MSH', '^~\\&', 'ADM', 'SHM', 'ALL', 'ALL', '20090101010000', 'ORU^R01', 'IHS-20090101010000.00830', 'P', '2.1\n'],
['PID', '1', '9081717170722.97472', 'RUBIE^ALBERT^ALLEN^^^AS', '19930812', 'M', '3250 DEL PASO BLVD^BUTTE^CHICO^CA^95973^USA', '393-41-9499', '393-41-9499\n']]
```

I created few functions to parse, delete empty elements and so on. At the end of the process, I'm iterating over the matrix and created a dictionary. However, I lose the order of each row in the dictionary...

```
{'IN1.0': {'IN1.0.0': 'IN1',
       'IN1.0.1': '1',
       'IN1.0.2': 'UNIT HLTH',
       'IN1.0.3': 'RUBIE^ALBERT^ALLEN^^^AS',
       'IN1.0.4': 'SELF'},
'MSH.0': {'MSH.0.0': 'MSH',
       'MSH.0.1': '^~\\&',
       'MSH.0.10': '2.1',
       'MSH.0.2': 'ADM',
       'MSH.0.3': 'SHM',
       'MSH.0.4': 'ALL',
       'MSH.0.5': 'ALL',
       'MSH.0.6': '20090101010000',
       'MSH.0.7': 'ORU^R01',
       'MSH.0.8': 'IHS-20090101010000.00830',
       'MSH.0.9': 'P'},
```

The `MSH` should be the first line in the object and it came 2nd. Also notice the `MSH.0.1` is followed by `MSH.0.10`. It looks like the dictionary in Python is sorting the keys by default. If so... How can I keep the order as `FIFO`?

Comment: `dict`s aren’t ordered; use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: if all the keys are just `MSH.0.X` why not just use a list where `X` is the indice?

Comment: `OrderDict()` changes the structure of the dictionary. Now it is a bid tuple with nested arrays with nested tuples. However, the order that is coming from the original hl7 is preserved.

Comment: @Gilbert It didn't change the format, just the output. try using `json.dumps(data, indent=2)` for printing purposes (assuming everything in the structure is suited for json.

Comment: Yep, I `print(json.dumps(data, indent=3)) and got the expected result.